# Programming editor with fetch code from web

Tags: c, vim, editor

I am looking for an editor which can take a Web URL as the source of the code tree. I work in a restrictive environment where I cannot clone the code base into my desktop. The only way is to use putty and login to the server and browse code using vim. But all the code can be copied into a web directory and is visible at a URL. So my idea is have an ediotr which can accept URL as the source of the code tree and show the files in the editor so that I can browse/edit in my desktop. I am looking for an editor in windows/Linux

Comment: `emacs` is able to do this with [TRAMP](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/)

Answer (score 1):

Both these commands let you list the content of a remote directory and choose what to edit:

```
$ vim ftp://[user@]machine/path/    <--- connect via FTP
$ vim scp://[user@]machine/path/    <--- connect via SSH
```

Use `:Rex` to go back to the listing after editing.

See `:help netrw`.

Answer (score 1):

Vim ships with the *netrw* plugin that allows to access and edit remote files. Just use

```
:edit http://server/path/to/file
```

That will fetch the file from the server and edit a temporary copy in your local Vim / GVIM. If you want to push back your changes to the server, you need a bi-directional protocol, such as SSH / SCP:

```
:edit scp://user@server/path/to/file
```

For details, see `:help netrw`.

Comment: I am looking for a GUI based editor like eclipse, where navigating code is easy. I can always login to the server through putty and edit/browse files in VIM. I want a desktop based GUI editor

Comment: GVIM is a GUI editor, and with a tags database, you can also navigate the code. Or do you mean a fully-fledged IDE (where text editor is only a small part of the whole suite)?

Comment: @nikhil In that case, I would suggest using a more appropriate set of tags for your question. Also, I don't quite understand how your environment is so restrictive that you can't download the code, but you *can* install an IDE?